# How to set max limit for each word in the sentence using Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string, limit, string-length

I want to throw an error when the word exceeds max length, but not the whole sentence length.

Example

if I am setting max length as 10, the sentence is `"Hello stackOverflow"` this should throw error since stackoverflow length more than 10 if I give as  `"Hello stack Overflow"` Should be passed since none of the word is not exceeding max length 10. This should be achieved using Regex in Java

Comment: `regex` might **not** be the best solution to your problem. `regex` *are not meant for throwing errors. You would need to throw the error manually in case of failed match* but the match can fail due to variety of reasons depending on the regex applied.

Comment: Yes, I can throw error, I need regex code to find the match

Comment: *Could you mention the string format* - what is made up of? It will help in constructing the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet does what you request using the sample string in your question.

```java
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\w{11,}");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello stackOverflow");
if (matcher.find()) {
    throw new Exception("Word too long.");
}
```

The regular expression searches for a series of at least eleven word characters and throws an exception if a match is found.

Comment: This is the right way to solve this issue. Check for reasons to reject, not reasons to accept.